# Converting Member Function Pointer to TIMERPROC

Tags: c++, winapi, casting, pointer-to-member

How do I convert a member function pointer to the `TIMERPROC` type for use with the WINAPI `SetTimer`?  The code snippet below shows how I'm doing it now, but when I compile I get this error:

> error C2664: 'SetTimer' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'void (__stdcall CBuildAndSend::* )(HWND,UINT,UINT_PTR,DWORD)' to 'TIMERPROC'

The callback needs to be tied to its originating class instance.  If there is a better way to do that, I'm all ears.  Thanks.

```
class CMyClass
{
public:
    void (CALLBACK CBuildAndSend::*TimerCbfn)( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime );

private:
    void CALLBACK TimeoutTimerProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime );
};

CMyClass::CMyClass()
{
    ...

    this->TimerCbfn = &CBuildAndSend::TimeoutTimerProc;

    ...

    ::CreateThread(
        NULL,                           // no security attributes
        0,                              // use default initial stack size
        reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(BasThreadFn), // function to execute in new thread
        this,                           // thread parameters
        0,                              // use default creation settings
        NULL                            // thread ID is not needed
        )
}

void CALLBACK CMyClass::TimeoutTimerProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime )
{
    ...
}

static DWORD MyThreadFn( LPVOID pParam )
{
    CMyClass * pMyClass = (CMyClass *)pParam;

    ...

    ::SetTimer( NULL, 0, BAS_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, pMyClass->TimerCbfn ); // <-- Error Here

    ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing User Data with SetTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625184/passing-user-data-with-settimer)

Comment: BTW, any time you have a cast with a function (or function pointer) in a win32 API, it usually indicates there's some sort of error. If it doesn't compile as-is, then usually the function needs to be changed; adding a cast is just papering over the problem. Lucky for you, turns out that C++ (pointers to) member functions are a completely different beast than (pointers to) plain functions, so not even reinterpret_cast is possible in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Member-function and TIMEPROC are not compatible types.

You need to make the member function `static`. Then it will work, assuming parameter-list is same in both, static member  function and TIMEPROC.

```
class CMyClass
{
public:
    //modified
    void (CALLBACK *TimerCbfn)(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime);

private:
    //modified
    static void CALLBACK TimeoutTimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime );
};
```

Function pointer as well as member function both are modified. Now  it should work.

Now since the callback function became static, it cannot access the non-static members of the class, because you don't have `this` pointer in the function.

To access the non-static members, you can do this:

```
class CMyClass
{
public:

    static void CALLBACK TimerProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime );

    //add this static member
    static std::map<UINT_PTR, CMyClass*> m_CMyClassMap; //declaration
};

//this should go in the  CMyClass.cpp file
std::map<UINT_PTR, CMyClass*> CMyClass::m_CMyClassMap;  //definition

static DWORD MyThreadFn( LPVOID pParam )
{
    CMyClass * pMyClass = (CMyClass *)pParam;

    UINT_PTR id = ::SetTimer( NULL, 0, BAS_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, CMyClass::TimerProc);

    //store the class instance with the id as key!        
    m_CMyClassMap[id]= pMyClass; 
}

void CALLBACK CMyClass::TimerProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime )
{
    //retrieve the class instance
    CMyClass *pMyClass= m_CMyClassMap[idEvent];

    /*
      now using pMyClass, you can access the non-static 
      members of the class. e.g
      pMyClass->NonStaticMemberFunction();
    */
}
```

I removed `TimerCbfn` from my implementation, as it doesn't really needed. You can pass `TimerProc` directly to `SetTimer` as last  argument.

Comment: Just using a static member function isn't enough if you really want to call a member function! You probably want to pass the instance pointer as the timer ID and then when WM_TIMER is received, reverse the process and invoke the method on the object instance.

Comment: Thanks!  To get it to compile I also had to declare static any member variables the static member callback function referenced.  Can I still expect there to be a separate instance of each member variable/function for each instance of the class that is created?  Or, because they are declared static, is every instance of the class going to reference a single variable or function?  If the latter is the case, that is going to be a problem.

Comment: @David Heffernan: That's a great idea!  Submit it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually it's more complex than that. Windows allocates the IDs for you. So you need a static map between IDs and instances. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625184/passing-user-data-with-settimer

Comment: Another good article here: http://www.greengingerwine.com/index.php/2011/05/using-the-windows-settimer-api-with-cpp-objects/

Comment: But personally I'd opt for a library timer, or a windowed timer where the window class stores the instance references. I really don't like window less timers.

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry I have misled you. This doesn't work. Windows allocates the IDs: "If the hWnd parameter is NULL, and the nIDEvent does not match an existing timer then it is ignored and a new timer ID is generated."

Comment: @David: Yeah.It seems. Actually this tricks usually works with Windows other APIs. But this is a bit different. :D

Comment: @Nawaz: This looks good; I'll have to try it when I get back into the office on Monday (about to head out the door now). :)

Comment: @David Heffernan: I was working on using `CreateWindow` to make a hidden window whose handle could be used in `SetTimer`.  That wouldn't work?

Comment: @Nawaz: I tried your implementation.  The source module compiles okay, but when I do a build build, I get this link error: `2>MyClass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::map<unsigned int,class CMyClass *,struct std::less<unsigned int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned int const ,class CMyClass *> > > CMyClass::m_CMyClassMap" (?m_CMyClassMap@CMyClass@@2V?$map@IPAVCMyClass@@U?$less@I@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBIPAVCMyClass@@@std@@@3@@std@@A)
`  Any ideas?

Comment: @Jim: You need to define the static data member outside the class as well. See my answer again. I've marked it where this should go.

Comment: @Jim: Especially pay attention to this line : `std::map<UINT_PTR, CMyClass*> CMyClass::m_CMyClassMap;  //definition`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks!  I had overlooked that part.  The windowed solution suggested by David is also good, but for what I'm doing, this is much simpler, and I think will raise fewer questions during peer review.  Kudos!

Comment: @Nawaz: I finished making other necessary changes to my application, but now when I run it, I'm getting a first-change exception when `CMyClass` is instantiated.  Do you have any ideas as to what is causing this?  The only think I can think of is that it has something to do with the addition of `std::map`.

Comment: @Jim: What is `first-change exception`?

Comment: @Nawaz: I don't really know. ^_^;;  I'm just an embedded guy doing my best in a Windows world.  It's what the output window in VS says: `First-chance exception at 0x0526a9de (MyApp.dll) in ParentApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.`  This happens as soon as `new CMyClass(...)` is called.  The PC doesn't even get to the first line in the constructor, if I set a breakpoint there.

Comment: @Nawaz: Here you go: http://ideone.com/NB8AW  It should be noted that the thread function is fired off from member function `Send`.  Also, I noticed that my calls to `KillTimer` are incorrect, but that shouldn't matter at this point because, as is, the PC never gets there.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: dead link! Archived page: http://web.archive.org/web/20150209024130/http://www.greengingerwine.com/index.php/2011/05/using-the-windows-settimer-api-with-cpp-objects/