# how do I pass a parameter to settimer?

Tags: c++

I have a timer:

```
SetTimer(0, 0, 200, (TIMERPROC) & TimerProc);
```

As well as the ProcTimer function:

```
void TimerProc(int a)
{
    printf("Hello");
}
```

how do I pass parameter **a** to the timer?

Comment: How is `SetTimer` declared?

Comment: @Galik It's [the Win32 SetTimer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing User Data with SetTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625184/passing-user-data-with-settimer)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that `SetTimer` simply doesn't support passing a parameter to the timer proc.

There are a couple of ways you can get around that if you really need to. One is to put the data in a global variable, and retrieve it from the global in the timer proc. If you might have more than one timer outstanding at a time, you can put the data into something like an `std::map`, with the timer ID as the key into the map (but this can get a little ugly if you need to pass different types of data to the different timer procs--still possible with something like `std::variant`, but ugly nonetheless).

But honestly, it's just easier and cleaner to simply avoid the problem entirely. `SetTimer` is mostly a hold-over from 16-bit Windows. If it works well for what you want, go ahead and use it--but in a case like this where it doesn't fit the need, use something else. In this case, the simplest way to handle the situation is probably to just spin up a thread:

```cpp
int a = 1234;

t = std::thread([a] {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms); 
    printf("Received parameter: %d\n", a);
};
```

Comment: well, can I use a **non-static TimerProc()** function to implement a timer? 
**.h:**

`void __stdcall TimerProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime);`

**.cpp:**

`void __stdcall Main::TimerProc() {
 printf("Hello func\n");

}

TimerId = SetTimer(nullptr, TimerId, 100, (TIMERPROC)TimerProc);`

i got error **invalid type conversion**

Comment: @Y0MMY: as you've already found, no--a TimerProc has to be either a free function or a static member function. If you need to pass data, you probably want a thread.

Answer (score 0):

create another global variable and assign a to this variable?

```
//like this
int b;

int f(int a) {
    b = a;
    //do something.
}
```

or you can directly put the SetTimer function into the TimerProc function.

```
//like this
void TimerProc(int a)
{
    SetTimer(0, 0, 200, (TIMERPROC) & TimerProc); //this function can use a as parameter.
    printf("Hello");
}
```

Comment: This neither is a solution to the question, nor is it relevant.